# Javascript if select 'other' then populate input field

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple select drop down. What I am trying to do is have... The user select a insurance company name. However, if the user does not see the company they're with then I would like to have an 'other' option which will populate a input so that the user can manually type the insurance company in.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    <h3><b>Insurance Information</b></h3>
    <style> #InsuranceCompanyOther{display:none;}</style>
    <script>$('p select[name=InsuranceCompany]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=InsuranceCompany]').val() == ''){
    $('#InsuranceCompanyOther').show();
  }else{
    $('#InsuranceCompanyOther').hide();
  }
});</script>
    <div class="control-group">   
                <label class="control-label">Insurance Comapny</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select  class="form-control" name="InsuranceCompany">
                            <option value="<?php echo !empty($InsuranceCompany)?$InsuranceCompany:'';?>"><?php echo !empty($InsuranceCompany)?$InsuranceCompany:'-- Select One --';?></option>            
                            <option value="Allstate">Allstate</option>
                            <option value="State Farm">State Farm</option>
                            <option value="Farmers">Farmers</option>
                            <option value="Travelers">Travelers</option>
                            <option value="Safeco">Safeco</option>
                            <option value="USAA">USAA</option>
                            <option value="MetLife">MetLife</option>
                            <option value="Farm Bureau">Farm Bureau</option>
                            <option value="Gem State">Gem State</option>
                            <option value="Amica">Amica</option>
                            <option value="American Family">American Family</option>
                            <option value="">Other</option>
                        </select>
                         <div id="InsuranceCompanyOther">
                            <p>Please Specify: <label id="InsuranceCompanyOther"><input name="InsuranceCompany" type="text" placeholder="Input Insurance Company" size="50" /></label></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

P.S. I dont believe this is worthy to down vote...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u5u1seza/

Comment: get a ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Execute the fiddle before commenting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coreections you need to do in your code are:

1. You javascript code should be in `document.ready`, as script is
   getting loaded before html and in this it is attaching events to
   element that is not on DOM yet.
2. The tag `select[name=InsuranceCompany]` is not within `p` tag
   therefore remove `p` from jQuery selector.

Working Snippet:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('select[name=InsuranceCompany]').change(function(e) {
    if ($('select[name=InsuranceCompany]').val() == '') {
      $('#InsuranceCompanyOther').show();
    } else {
      $('#InsuranceCompanyOther').hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><b>Insurance Information</b></h3>
<style>
  #InsuranceCompanyOther {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Insurance Comapny</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select class="form-control" name="InsuranceCompany">
      <option value="<?php echo !empty($InsuranceCompany)?$InsuranceCompany:'';?>">
        <?php echo !empty($InsuranceCompany)?$InsuranceCompany: '-- Select One --';?>
      </option>
      <option value="Allstate">Allstate</option>
      <option value="State Farm">State Farm</option>
      <option value="Farmers">Farmers</option>
      <option value="Travelers">Travelers</option>
      <option value="Safeco">Safeco</option>
      <option value="USAA">USAA</option>
      <option value="MetLife">MetLife</option>
      <option value="Farm Bureau">Farm Bureau</option>
      <option value="Gem State">Gem State</option>
      <option value="Amica">Amica</option>
      <option value="American Family">American Family</option>
      <option value="">Other</option>
    </select>
    <div id="InsuranceCompanyOther">
      <p>Please Specify:
        <label>
          <input name="InsuranceCompany" type="text" placeholder="Input Insurance Company" size="50" />
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Include **jQuery** library in you code, example CDN:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined which is giving me the on document load

Comment: I do, I have jQuery-2.1.4.min.js at the bottom of my page., however adding 2.1.1 worked... Hrmm.

Comment: @Levi : Include jquery on top(head) of the page. Here the execution is top to bottom, now you are using `$` <- jQuery object before loading jQuery therefore it is undefined.